# Why doesn't my view update when adding items to the ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

So I have this project where I have two buttons and a ListView. The ListView is separated into it's own `UserControl` with it's own `ViewModel` which contains a `ObservableCollection`.

I'm using a `ContentPresenter` to display that control because I will be using different views.

Currently, when I'm clicking the `Log` button, it does in fact add the string to the collection, but the view doesn't update. And it keeps adding more and more everytime I click on it. (I've put a breakpoint inside `private void AddItemOne()` to inspect it to prove that it adds items.)

***Question***
Why doesn't my view update when I click the "Log" button even though it's adding items.
It does add the first item if I hardcode it like this.

```
public LogViewModel()
{
    Logs = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    Logs.Add("Test");
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="25" Content="Log" 
            Command="{Binding AddItemOneCommand}"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="25" Content="Other"
            Command="{Binding AddItemTwoCommand}"/>

    <UserControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
</Grid>
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
class MainViewModel
{
    public RelayCommand AddItemOneCommand { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand AddItemTwoCommand { get; set; }


    private object _currentView;

    public object CurrentView
    {
        get { return _currentView; }
        set
        {
            _currentView = value;
        }
    }


    /* ViewModels */
    public LogViewModel LogViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        AddItemOneCommand = new RelayCommand(o => AddItemOne());
        AddItemTwoCommand = new RelayCommand(o => AddItemTwo());

        LogViewModel = new LogViewModel();

        _currentView = LogViewModel;


    }

    private void AddItemOne()
    {
        LogViewModel.Logs.Add("Test");
    }


    private void AddItemTwo()
    {
        LogViewModel.Logs.Add("Test");
    }
}
```

**LogView.xaml**

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:LogViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Logs}" Background="Gray"/>
</Grid>
```

**LogViewModel.cs**

```
class LogViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Logs { get; set; }

    public LogViewModel()
    {
        Logs = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }
}
```

***Misc***

**App.xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LogViewModel}">
        <local:LogView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

And the RelayCommand

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this from LogView.xaml:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:LogViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

It creates another instance of the `LogViewModel` instead of using the one that you create in the `MainViewModel`.

You should also replace the `UserControl` in MainWindow.xaml with a `ContentControl` that binds to the `CurrentView` property:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

Comment: What is the rationale behind the use of the `ContentControl` instead of a `UserControl`?

Comment: It will apply the template defined in `App.xaml` based on the value of the `Content` property.

Comment: If I remove the `<UserControl.DataContext>` will that not make it to where I can't bind to data? Or does it aotumagically apply the datacontext when you do the `ContentControl` binding?

Comment: Yes. It applies the template and the `UserControl` in the template will inherit the `Content` as its `DataContext`.

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you!